# IE 9 problems with "New Navigation Release Candidate"

Tags: bug, new-nav

As discussed with @sklivvz here a bug report regarding IE9 and the new navigation:

[image]

**JavaScript Error:**

```
Line: 4
Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'replaceState'
```

Comment: Do you have custom styles enabled? Because that's not what our site looks like, and there is absolutely nothing in the tabs code that would alter the styles of the tags in that manner. (Note: this is only in reference to the odd stylings in your screenshot.)

Comment: no i don't have any custom styles enabled @animuson

Comment: it seems it's a javascript error, can you check your console?

Comment: @Sklivvz see updated answer